# Is playing video games such as Skyrim shirk?

Tags: shirk, game

I used to play a game called *Skyrim*. It was a really good game and I recommended it to all my friends.

But in the game, there is magic as well as polytheism, as there are many gods eg: if you get a disease you go to a god's shrine and get yourself healed. You can also wear amulets to get power boosts and you can also use shrines in your homes.

When I played the game I pretended that I was the protagonist but now I feel like I have committed shirk.

Comment: By Playing video games you are just sitting in front of your computer and using your mind, as far as I know in Islam thoughts cannot be considered as sins, only acting on those thoughts could. So as long as you don't go out in your real world and start worshiping Skyrim's Gods, you should be fine.

Comment: Actions are judged by intentions. Your actions were part of an act in a make-believe world. You know the nine are not capable of benefiting or harming you, you don't ask for their blessings at shrines in real life .... indeed no one ever has, even in the past ever worshiped or believed in them, they are purely fictional entities. Maybe nextime you play skyrim pretend that the Dragonborn has converted to Islam, throw a fireball at the shrines to show your rejection and mod-in a mosque and get your diseases healed there. :)