# Does worshipping a God in game negate my virtue?

Tags: software, game

I just start playing a *multiplayer* PC game called [Conan Exiles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWX16KviBWM). In the beginning of the game, one must select a religion (not Islam) out of four, as character builds up.

Worshipping a God gives you help in later levels, as you would be able to summon titans and other beings by worshipping that God.

I am playing this game just for fun. **Does selecting and praying for a God in game negate my virtue in any way?**

Comment: This question has been answered before http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24792/is-playing-video-games-such-as-skyrim-shirk

Comment: Thankyou @Armaan, The question is relatively similar, but it is still unanswered, would you like to answer it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'exile my virtue'?

Comment: waste my emaan, my aqeedah, i hope it's clear now

Comment: Thanks. Based on what you said, the game is for entertainment and is permissible if one doesn't become ignorant of salah. However such games can tempt you to commit actual shirk and think these thoughts. If you think these evil thoughts, then it is the shayateen tempting you and not a sin so you should stop playing the game. If one has good eeman, then you wouldn't play these games but it won't affect your eeman if it doesn't entice you to evil actions.

Comment: Thanks @Armaan, post a proper answer(with references), so it would be more understandable.